# compileinplace with non-serializable type

Tags: serializable

I am using CompileInPlace to handle preparing to serialize a type based on its runtime type since at compile time I only know it is derived from object.

Unlike PrepareSerialize, however, I get no indication with CompileInPlace if the type passed to it is not serializable.  Instead, I only get an exception later when I try to serialize the object.

Is there some way to verify that the object is actually serializable ahead of time, i.e. when I call CompileInPlace?

Comment: The type I'm calling CompileInPlace is an abstract class.  I am using protobuf-net 2.1.0.  I will test the latest.

Comment: CompileInPlace in protobuf-net 2.4.0. also doesn't complain about being called with a type that is abstract.  I did verify that ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.CanSerialize returns false for the abstract class, in both 2.1.0 and 2.4.0.

Comment: Can't you just handle the exception?